# clang-format does not modify file on disk

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have the following  badly formatted file, `test.cpp`

```
#include "maininclude.h"

int main() {
             class SIMPLE smpl;
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; 
  i++) {
      printf("Printing %d", i); // Trying out different stuff...
getchar();
  }
}
```

on which I want to run `clang-format`. Prior to running this, to visually see the places that are going to be modified, I run `clang-format -n test.cpp`. This correctly identifies the spots that will be changed due to bad formatting and outputs on the terminal:

```
test.cpp:3:13: warning: code should be clang-formatted [-Wclang-format-violations]
int main() {
            ^
test.cpp:5:27: warning: code should be clang-formatted [-Wclang-format-violations]
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; 
                          ^
test.cpp:6:9: warning: code should be clang-formatted [-Wclang-format-violations]
  i++) {
        ^
test.cpp:7:64: warning: code should be clang-formatted [-Wclang-format-violations]
          printf("Printing %d", i); // Trying out different stuff...
                                                                    ^
```

On running `clang-format test.cpp`, I obtain how the correctly formatted file would look like (this display is on the terminal):

```
#include "maininclude.h"

int main() {
  class SIMPLE smpl;
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("Printing %d", i); // Trying out different stuff...
    getchar();
  }
}
```

Yet, running the above command does not change the actual `test.cpp` file on disk. Is there a separate option/command to have `clang-format` go ahead and apply its changes and save the file on disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man clang-format`:

```
       -i                         - Inplace edit <file>s, if specified.
```

Comment: Indeed, this did the trick. So, by design, `clang-format test.cpp` outputs what the file would look like on the terminal alone.

Comment: @Tryer yes, this is a standard behavior. Pretty much all unix tools work that way: don't modify user data unless they explicitly request it.

Comment: @spectras yes, and by experience don't use the same source and sink because it sometimes corrupts the file (e.g. `tool A.txt > A.txt`). Not sure if this applies to `clang-format`.

Comment: Indeed. This is true with any tool because with such syntax `A.txt` gets cleared *before* `tool` starts.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-i` option, which means `Inplace edit <file>s`. It will edit the file in place.

Comment: You only think it will?

Comment: @sweenish, I was trying to get the required 38 characters for an answer. My first attempt, "Use the `-i` option" was too short, so I added "useless" words. By the time I submitted the answer for the second time, it wasn't the first answer anymore. I've removed the "I think it will" though. Thanks.